# more efficient way to select duplicate users

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

Im trying to select `*` from all duplicate rows in users, where a duplicate is defined as two users sharing the same `first_name` and `last_name`. (I need to process the other columns that might differ)

Im using MySQL 8.0.28.

My first try was to literally translate my requirement:

```
select * from `users` AS u1 where exists (select 1 from `users` AS u2 WHERE `u2`.`first_name` = `u1`.`first_name` AND `u2`.`last_name` = `u1`.`last_name` AND `u2`.`id` != `u1`.`id`)
```

Which, obviously, has a horrendous execution time.

My current query is

```
SELECT * from users where  Concat(first_name," ",last_name) IN (select Concat(first_name," ",last_name) from `users` GROUP BY first_name, last_name HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

which is vastly more efficient, but still takes more than 100ms for 8000 records. I suppose a solution that doesn't use concat could benefit from indicies and would not need to calculate the result for each row.

Also, I couldn't get `group by` to work because I need so select all columns of all rows that are duplicates, not just the distinct `first_name`'s and `last_name`'s. Also because I don't want to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` (not sure if disabling that would help anyway).

Is there a more efficient, proper way to select these duplicate rows?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us your table definition. If it has a primary key (an `id` column) that will serve as a useful way to get an efficient solution to your problem.

Comment: @O.Jones the answer from Tim Biegeleisen is already what was looking for, also I thought that its obvious from my first query that `id` is the primary key. Should I have made it more explicit?

Comment: @dsalex1 Generally, when asking SQL questions, both sample input and expected result should be shown as tables in the question, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE (first_name, last_name) IN (
    SELECT first_name, last_name
    FROM users
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

On MySQL 8+, we can also use `COUNT()` as an analytic function here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name) AS cnt
    FROM users
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tried something similar to the first query, but I must got the syntax wrong then and thought it doesnt work in general. Interesstingly in my sample of 8000 records the `PARTITION BY` query performs worse than the `CONCAT` one. But good to know something like `count over partition by` exists anyway.

Comment: @dsalex1 Perhaps...but keep in mind that first + last can lead to problems, e.g. `joe` + `blow` = `joeb` + `low`